# selectableItemBackgroundBorderless for textview

Tags: android, textview, geometry, effect

I have a `TextView` which is use as a button. I want to add attribute `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` to have circle ripple effect when pressing. The layout is as following:

```
android:id="@+id/create_button"  
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="54dp"
...
android:background="? android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

As a result, indeed the circle ripple effect when pressing, but the ripple goes out of the textview, but just out of the bottom of textview (because the top of the textview is action bar).

My question is, why ripple effect gets across the textview bottom? As you know, I have limited `android:layout_height` to 54dp. Why this limitation is useless?

Answer (score 25):

You have to use `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground` to keep the ripple effect inside the `View` boundaries.

`?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` allows the effect to go outside of the `View`.

Comment: Yes, but how to get circle ripple effect ? Just like action bar button pressing effect.

Comment: You should have it if you run your application on Android 5.0+.

Comment: I am running on Android 5.1. But the rippe goes out of the textview from bottom.

Comment: Hi, I fixed this issue today. We need to add a background for the layout which includes the button, then the rippe effect will be limited in the button border. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: My problem is the ripple is clipped inside the textView's parent.How to make the ripple goes out of the textView's parent?

Comment: @AllenVork try to set `android:clipChildren="false" and if necessary `android:clipToPadding="false"` on the parent.

Answer (score 7):

1.To limit the ripple effect inside the view only you need to specify

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

inside the view.

2.For making ripple effect border less i.e show ripple effect in whole layout you can use this.

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

3.For more you can check the link [Defining Custom Animation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html)